# What is the fastest / easiest way to Upgrade to Rspec 3.x

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec3

I have Rspec 2.14.7 but I have a test suite that uses functionality from Rspec 3.x. What is the easiest way to upgrade to 3.x?

I have checked the upgrade docs at RSpec website, but the screencasts don't make any sense to me. I've tried the commands it gives me error on bash shell. (http://rspec.info/upgrading-from-rspec-2/)

Comment: Which command did you try and what is error you got?

Comment: Plines is just an example project that is being upgraded from RSpec 2 to RSpec 3 in the videos.  If the videos don't make sense to you than ignore them.  The directions at rspec.info is going to be the best way to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the recipe:

- Be green and warning free on RSpec 2
- `gem "rspec", "~> 2.99"`
- `bundle install`
- Fix warnings
- `gem "rspec", "~> 3.0"`

Done.

There is also [Transpec](http://yujinakayama.me/transpec/). Use it!